# Sending a message to a window that belongs to another thread. Possible Deadlock?

Tags: c++, windows, deadlock

I think i am ruining in to a deadlock, have been searching for the solution over hours. Any suggestions?
What i am trying to do is: ater startGame button click, create thread that send request to the server and then gets the answer, after the answer the thread must send a message to Initialize game window to the main proc...

Message Proc that belongs to WinMain:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND myWindow, UINT messg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
   {
        switch (messg) {
               case WM_STARTGAME:
            DestroyWindow(hStartGameButton);
            DestroyWindow(hHistoryButton);

            InitGameWindow(myWindow);
        break;


                case WM_COMMAND:

                  switch(LOWORD(wParam))
                  {
                        case IDC_STARTGAME_BUTTON:
                        {
                          parametros param;
                          param.myWindow = myWindow;

                          start_game = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ThreadStartGame, (LPVOID)&myWindow, 0, NULL);
                        }

                  }
   }
```

And this is the thread:

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadStartGame(LPVOID param){
HWND w = (HWND)param;
DWORD n;
BOOL ret;
mensagem resposta;


mensagem msg;
msg.tipo = COMECAR_JOGO;
msg.verifica = true;

if (!WriteFile(hPipe, &msg, (DWORD)sizeof(mensagem), &n, NULL)) {return 0;}

    ret = ReadFile(hPipeN, &resposta, (DWORD)sizeof(mensagem), &n, NULL);
    if (!ret || !n) {
        return false;
     }

PostMessage(w, WM_STARTGAME, NULL, NULL); // <- THIS GETS EXECUTED BUT NOTHINK HAPPENS AFTER

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Windows don't belong to threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is any deadlock here.

```
start_game = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ThreadStartGame, (LPVOID)&myWindow, 0, NULL);
```

This line passes the address of the HWND to the thread (&myWindow)

`HWND w = (HWND)param;`

This line uses the adress itself as HWND and the SendMessage sends the message to this address which is not a HWND.

Try modifying to

`start_game = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ThreadStartGame, (LPVOID)myWindow, 0, NULL);`

Comment: thanks you, changing the 4th parameter from (LPVOID)&myWindow to (LPVOID)myWindow solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

W/o even looking at the code, I can tell you right away: do not use `SendMessage` between threads. I recommend reading [Psychic debugging: The first step in diagnosing a deadlock is a simple matter of following the money](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Preventing Hangs in Windows Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd744765%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Use asynchronous window message APIs in your UI thread, **especially by replacing `SendMessage` with one of its non-blocking peers**: `PostMessage`, `SendNotifyMessage`, or `SendMessageCallback`
>
> ...
>   Any blocking call that crosses thread boundaries has synchronization properties that can result in a deadlock. The calling thread performs an operation with 'acquire' semantics and cannot unblock until the target thread 'releases' that call. Quite a few User32 functions (**for example `SendMessage`**), as well as many blocking COM calls fall into this category.

Comment: thanks for the answer and the links, although when i tried PostMessage i still had the problem.

Comment: PermanentGuest showed the problem. My point is beyond the immediate fix: do not use `SendMessage` between threads, even after getting the correct HWND.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you're unlikely supposed to do that in the first place. Quoting [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> A thread in an executable that calls the C run-time library (CRT) should use the _beginthreadex and _endthreadex functions for thread management rather than CreateThread and ExitThread; this requires the use of the multithreaded version of the CRT. If a thread created using CreateThread calls the CRT, the CRT may terminate the process in low-memory conditions.

Second, your thread can be worker or UI thread, from the first type you must not call most of the window related functions, as it has no message pump. `DestroyWindow`  is such.  (So many times I tried to use MessageBox despite my own comment a few lines upper telling it's forbidden in that function ;).

From worker threads the usual method is to use `PostThreadMessage` and react on the UI thread. (If you have multiple UI threads, I don't know the rules, was never brave enough for that.)